# Why doesn't the express CORS middleware work when applied to the Parse server middleware via Nest.js?

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, middleware, nestjs

I recently rewrote an older server in Nest.js that uses Parse-server (the firebase-like back-end as a service product facebook shut down). We want to be able to apply the CORS middleware to both our nest routes and our parse routes.

main.ts (simplified)

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = NestFactory.create(AppModule)
    app.enableCors({
        origin: ['https://my-origin.com']
    })

    await app.listen(3000)
}
bootstrap()
```

app.module.ts (simplified)

```
@Module({/*module set up here*/})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
    constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService, private readonly parse: ParseService) {}

    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(this.parse.parseServer).forRoutes('/parse-path')
    }
}
```

The CORS middleware gets applied to my nest routes, but not my parse routes. The parse routes are just normal middleware. What is the reason for the middleware being applied to the Nest routes but not the Parse server routes?

Comment: Hey @RobertRowntree thanks for the comment. I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you rephrase or clarify your question?

Comment: how are you starting instance of parse-server? This OP normally delegates to ParseServer.js where you will find CORS midware config such as the following :  
   * @static app()
    api.use(middlewares.allowCrossDomain(appId));
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/ParseServer.js#L152